# How to prevent that the code indentation affects the rendering of elements with inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I have two elements containing divs with the **inline-block** property.

The code of the divs inside this container is not indented:

```
<div class="container-no-indentation">
    <div>
        <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the code of the divs inside this second container is indented:

```
<div class="container-indentation">
    <div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/a7purzk1/

If you run the jsfiddle you will se that the divs inside ".container-no-indentation" are
rendered more close each other than the divs within ".container-indentation".

Why is that happening and how can I prevent this behaviour?

Since the divs within ".container-no-indentation" are dynamically generated, they will always
be unindented, and I want them to be displayed like the divs inside ".container-indentation".

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

This is how I generate the divs:

```
var noIndent = document.querySelector(".container-no-indentation");

for (var i=0; i<7;i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = i+"";
    noIndent.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: Actually, OP wants opposite - to keep space... :)

Comment: How do you generate divs, can you add JS code?

Comment: @dfsq there is already a jsfiddle

Comment: Add a space character after every div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `float:left` to avoid the extra spaces.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a7purzk1/1/

(you might want to use `:after` pseudo element to clear the float, as in the example)

This happens because the `inline`-styled elements (`inline` and `inline-block`) take the whitespace into account. E.g. if you'd want to have an `inline-block` image in the middle of a text paragraph, you'd want it to have whitespace as you describe with spaces.

So basically there is an extra space between the divs. Browser just strips the spaces that you have maximum of one space between the elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a space between generated inline-bloke elements then you need to manually insert some whaitespace character after each one. In your case the simple approach is to append just simple textNode after `div`:

```
var noIndent = document.querySelector(".container-no-indentation > div");

for (var i = 0; i < 7;i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = i;
    noIndent.appendChild(div);
    noIndent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/a7purzk1/3/

Or if you want shorter:

```
noIndent.appendChild(div).insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add a value for the right margin on the `div`'s:

```css
.container-indentation,
.container-no-indentation {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
.container-no-indentation > div > div,
.container-indentation > div > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
.container-no-indentation > div > div {
  margin-right: 5px; /* use some suitable value */
}
```

```html
<h1>No indentation</h1>
<div class="container-no-indentation">
  <div>
    <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Indentation</h1>
<div class="container-indentation">
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```